# Custom XGB obj function

Tags: python, numpy, xgboost, objective-function

I'd like to preface by saying I'm pretty new to using xgboost, pandas, and numpy.

Currently I'm working on implementing a custom OBJ function for XGBoost based on the  kelly criterion.
This approach is drawn from another post on datascience.stackexchange: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/16186/kelly-criterion-in-xgboost-loss-function

From reading the documentation of XGBoost, I need to return the gradient and hessian. (https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/custom_metric_obj.html)
The gradient of the function is:

[image: gradient]

The hessian of the function is:

[image: hessian]

Where:

b = odds received on a wager

p = probability of winning

x = prediction from the algorithm

For this I'm going to treat p as a binary variable, 1 or 0, for whether the wager succeeded.

So, p = true outcome, 1 or 0

Using the documentation I wrote the following code, I've also provided a small sample dataset:

```
kell_train_data = np.array([0.08396877, 0.07131547, 0.17921676, 0.22317006, 0.06278754, 0.29874458, 0.08079682, 0.13074108, 0.06416036], 0.12209199, 0.10400956, 0.28764891, 0.2913481, 0.09450234, 0.07858831, 0.09246751, 0.17008012, 0.29026032, 0.2741014 , 0.05574227)

odds_train = np.array([0.149254, 0.108696, 0.312500, 0.217391, 0.061350, 0.208333, 0.178571, 0.065359, 0.037453, 0.107527, 0.256410, 0.400000, 0.370370,  0.085470, 0.058140, 0.204082, 0.476190, 0.294118, 0.121951, 0.033003])

y_train = np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]

kell_train_data = kell_train_data.reshape(kell_train_data.shape[0], -1)


def gradient(y_pred, y_true, odds = odds_train):
    "Compute gradient of betting function"
    
    
    return (((-(odds+1)*y_true +odds*y_pred+1)/((y_pred-1)(odds*y_pred+1))))

def hessian(y_pred, y_true, odds = odds_train):
    "compute hessian of betting function"
    
    return (-(((odds**2)*y_true )/(odds*y_pred+1)**2)-((1-y_true)/((1-y_pred)**2)))

def kellyobjfunc(y_pred, y_true, odds = odds_train) :
    "kelly objective function for xgboost"
    grad = gradient(y_pred, y_true, odds)
    hess = hessian(y_pred, y_true, odds)
    return grad, hess

kell_mod = xgb.XGBClassifier(objective = kellyobjfunc, maximize = True)

kell_mod.fit(kell_train_data, y_train)
```

However, when I run the above code I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-623-18279e95b288>", line 1, in <module>
    kell_mod.fit( kell_target, y_train)

  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py", line 422, in inner_f
    return f(**kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\sklearn.py", line 919, in fit
    callbacks=callbacks)

  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\training.py", line 214, in train
    early_stopping_rounds=early_stopping_rounds)

  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\training.py", line 101, in _train_internal
    bst.update(dtrain, i, obj)

  File "C:\Users\USERR\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py", line 1285, in update
    grad, hess = fobj(pred, dtrain)

  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\sklearn.py", line 49, in inner
    return func(labels, preds)

  File "<ipython-input-621-35f90873cb76>", line 14, in kellyobjfunc
    grad = gradient(y_pred, y_true, odds)

  File "<ipython-input-621-35f90873cb76>", line 5, in gradient
    return (((-(odds+1)*y_true +odds*y_pred+1)/((y_pred-1)(odds*y_pred+1))))

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

I'm not sure what's causing this issue.
Any insight or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the error.

In the gradient function the position of the parentheses was causing the  error.

```
def gradient(y_pred, y_true, odds = odds_train):
    "Compute gradient of betting function"
    
    
    return (((-(odds+1)*y_true +odds*y_pred+1)/((y_pred-1)(odds*y_pred+1))))
```

Should actually be:

```
def gradient(y_pred, y_true, odds = odds_train):
    "Compute gradient of betting function"
    
    
    return (((-(odds+1) * y_true +odds * y_pred+1)/((y_pred-1)*(odds*y_pred+1))))
```

Also, the xgb model should be:

```
kell_mod = xgb.XGBClassifier(obj = kellyobjfunc, maximize = True)
```

The code now executes successfully.